# Can I embed my Picasa video to play on my website?

Tags: video, embed, picasa

Is it possible to embed my Picasa videos (not the whole album) on my website so it plays directly on the website without redirecting back to Picasa (kinda like youtube embedded videos)? I've seen this done on another website but can't seem to get mine to work. Picasa keeps giving me the links and embedded code for a photo even tho the file I'm currently viewing is a video. Also, you can give suggestions for both google+ photos or picasaweb.google.com (they are the same thing), I don't mind.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload your video to YouTube and use their method.  Picasa has a direct upload link to YouTube. For more details check following link:-
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/PMc9U3y5Iy8

Comment: thanks for the reply. Ive tried this method before but it means I have to upload my videos twice. But the main reason why i cant use youtube is because my videos have copyright music that will get them taken down in minutes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JumpMan247 there is no need to say thanks.            http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer