# How to Embed Google picasa Video On Site

Tags: image, video-streaming, embed, selectionchanging

Hi i have some Video on My Google picasa  and when i click on the video i get this link

https://r3---sn-hgn7zn7l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=d12b9a329cfd4043&itag=18&source=picasa&requiressl=yes&mm=30&mn=sn-hgn7zn7l&ms=nxu&mv=m&pl=17&sc=yes&ei=8VfuWLLRCZWAco_lr8gK&mime=video/mp4&lmt=1492008542142511&mt=1492014985&ip=182.183.229.192&ipbits=8&expire=1492043889&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,sc,ei,mime,lmt&signature=284714E29FC72F9789DF2594D27E93244784C959.9B7CE4154F229529E061D0943E6472AFB1F20EC4&key=ck2&cpn=UKhNQ1dBjFjgDVJo&c=WEB&cver=1.20170411

I want to Embed The Video On My Website : i have seen some site who are using the google picasa videos on their site but i can find how they have done please help me out

Comment: The link you have yields a 403 forbidden response, which means even if you could embed it with HTML5, it would not work. I recommend looking at this post in stackoverflow with a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769930/can-i-embed-my-picasa-video-to-play-on-my-website

Comment: check this out one of the site have the same link and the video is working fine on this site http://prntscr.com/evnjgp
He have some how get the link to work  ::: i tried to get embed the link on one of online generator embeded code and was working but not quite well

Comment: You could try ask google support. I'm voting to close this off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I embed my Picasa video to play on my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769930/can-i-embed-my-picasa-video-to-play-on-my-website)